# Unable to integrate facebook like button

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like

I am trying to integrate the **Facebook like button** in my HTML page, but I am unable to integrate it. I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong. I am using **HTML5** way of integrating.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
.
.
.
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
.
.
.
<div id="container">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know what is wrong in above code. Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jsfiddle...its working fine

http://jsfiddle.net/ADNMM/

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```